# Pop-up only once per week using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup

I've been trying to add the cookies into my script , but it hasn't been working at all . I am using this for Tumblr - I thought it was working since I would click 'update' on my blog while in 'editing mode' and the popup would show , but when I exit out it would disappear . I thought it was normal since my browser probably knew I already saw the pop-up and wouldn't show it to me again . I told my friend to check out the blog for me and let me know if she sees any pop-up , but she told me she didn't see anything . I just want my popup to open once per week for each visitor on my blog .  Can anyone show me the correct code or tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var id = '#dialog';

if($.cookie('.window') != 'seen'){
    $.cookie('.window', 'seen', { expires: 7, path: '/' }); // Set it to last a year, for example.
    $j(".window").delay(2000).fadeIn();
    $j('close').click(function(e) // You are clicking the close button
        {
        $j('.window').fadeOut(); // Now the pop up is hiden.
    });
    $j('.window').click(function(e) 
        {
        $j('.window').fadeOut(); 
    });
};

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();


//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect
$('#mask').show(1000);
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.5);


//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).show(2000);  

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
//Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();


$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});


//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('.window').hide();
});




});

</script>
```

This is the other part of the code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js">
</script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using local storage. It's like a cookie, but for javascript. It's also less complicated. W3 has a tutorial about it.

Comment: I tried reading up on it but it isn't clear to me. There's " lastname " and "smith " . I'm not entirely sure what to put there or how to use it in my code.